Should we add a CHAINMAIL tag?
CHAINMAIL was a set of wargaming tabletop rules, that contributed to the creation of our hobby of RPGs, by initially providing a "Fantasy Supplement" that allowed including creatures like goblins, orcs, trolls, elementals, wizards and dragons; those rules were then adopted by Dave Arneson to create the first role playing experience, and led Gary Gygax to create D&D with Arneson's input. In the original version of D&D, the CHAINMAIL rules were still the default way to resolve combat.
In a recent question about some of the rules interactions, I did not think much to tag the question with chainmail, because usually we use game rules systems even for fringe games, and advise querants in our Q&A to always provide information about the game they are asking about (but that could of course also be done in the body of the question).
There are a few other questions that mention "chainmail" together with OD&D, or history of gaming but many of the questions with the word are about the armor type, so this tag could lead to confusion, if people tag questions about the type of armor with chainmail, and that tag is about the battle simulation system, not armor.
Should we use a tag for the system, and what should its name be?

I for now retagged it to [chainmail-system] that seems to be the way we do it for other systems with double entendre names, like the d20 system, d6-system, cypher-system, hero system and storyteller-system.

Are there old questions about that system that should should get that tag or not?

@TreeSpawned There are a couple you can find a starting point in the links above, we just need to be careful not to flood the homepage with retags [a mistake I made when I was new here]. Usually such retagging projects can also be asked as a Q here, but in this case, I see maybe a dozen questions, so it probably is overkill, as long as you do not do more than 4-5 a day. Maybe wait for someone else to confirm in comment it is OK -- I tend to be too lose about these things for the taste of other community members.

Me, half-paying-attention. Why on Earth would we need an entire tag about a specific type of armor. We can't possibly have that many questions on Armor, let alone chainmail armor.

Complication: WOTC recycled the name "Chainmail" in the early 2000's for a completely different miniatures skirmish game line (later renamed "D&D Miniatures Skirmish Game").

Any chance that you might accept my answer and we can go ahead and burminate that tag?

@TreeSpawned Yes of course. Thank you!

We don't need a new tag, we already have one
The Chainmail System is already covered by the odnd tag. Its description has a second sentence in brackets which reads:

This tag also covers some questions about Chainmail, a predecessor wargame to which D&D was originally written partly as an expansion.

This is how all question about the rules of chainmail have been tagged so far and I don't think we need to change that. If we have a separate tag for it, but all question with that tag are also tagged odnd, then this is just unecessary redundancy.
The only reason I can see creating a seperate tag for Chainmail is if someone asks a question that is only about Chainmail, the base game, without any connection to Dungeons and Dragons. This however might not even be on-topic for this site, as I am not sure if Chainmail is even considered a roleplaying game. It might be better suited for the boardgaming site, which interestingly already has a Chainmail tag, which has a single question.
Update: In accordance with community consensus and with the approval of @NobodyTheHobgoblin I have now burninated chainmail-system by removing it from the one question it was used in.

Use [chainmail-system]
For other systems with double entendre names, like the d20 system, d6 system, cypher system, hero system and storyteller system we append system to the tag (e.g. d20-system).
So I propose we do the same here and use chainmail-system. This will avoid that someone who has a question about the weight of chainmail or such will accidentally use this tag to tag it, and it also is consistent with how we do it elsewhere.

All of those are officially called 'X system', though. The '-system' appendix hasn't been added by the stackexchange users to disambiguate them; those are the actual names.

The preceding is a fair comment. I'd suggest [chainmail-rules], given that the full title on the cover is "Chainmail: Rules for Medieval Miniatures".
